# How to declare objects dynamically in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

If today is 3rd, I want to make three obejects.

```
Dim Obj1 As Object

Dim Obj2 As Object

Dim Obj3 As Object
```

If today is 5th, I want to make three obejects.

```
Dim Obj1 As Object

Dim Obj2 As Object

Dim Obj3 As Object

Dim Obj4 As Object

Dim Obj5 As Object
```

Then how do I declare objects dynamically like this?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: if you want an uncertain number of objects you'll want to hold them in an array or list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu'll have to keep them in an array or list or some other kind of collection. Here's how you can achieve it:

```
Dim objects = New List(Of Object)

For i = 1 To Date.Today.Day
    objects.Add(New Object())
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list of objects may work for what you what:

```
Dim objs As List(Of Object) = New List(Of [Object])()
Dim day As Integer = DateTime.Today.Day

For i As Integer = 1 To day
    Dim o As Object = New Object()
    objs.Add(o)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility

```
Dim Objects As New List(Of Object)(Enumerable.Repeat(New Object, Date.Now.Day))
```